# Get the values ​of a tuple in other a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to get the first value of each Key. But I don't know how to get that value from a tuple in other a tuple.

```
(Key1(typekey=10, typecod=11),Key2(typekey=12, typecod=10)...)
```

This is the return from a database and I would need to make a column called "Keys" and the rows would be given `[typekey=10],[typekey=12]...` .

Like that:

Keys

```
typekey=10
typekey=12
...
```

If anyone knows how I can do this I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you assign to a variable, e.g., `foo = (Key1(typekey=10, typecod=11),Key2(typekey=12, typecod=10)...)` and give us a hint what `Key1`, `Key2` and etc... are? Best is if you can have a running example. Exclude the database call if you can and just make up some dummy data.

Comment: For a tuple in a tuple you could do somethign like `(val[0] for val in foo)` (assuming `foo` references the outer tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are named tuples, so you can access the elements as attributes.

Simply do this in a loop over the outer tuple.

```
for row in yourTuple:
    print(f"typekey={row.typekey}")
```